# Detecting failed insertion in Room Database when OnConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE

Tags: android-room

I'm developing an app in Kotlin that uses a room database, based on the well known example "Room Database With a View"

Relevant code snippets:

Main Activity:

```
siniestroViewModel.insert(taller)
```

View Model:

```
    fun nuevo(siniestro: Siniestro)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.nuevo(siniestro)
    }
```

Repository:

```
   suspend fun nuevo(siniestro: Siniestro){
       siniestroDao.nuevo(siniestro)
    }
```

Dao:

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun nuevo(siniestro: Siniestro)
```

This code prevents inserting a duplicate record and it works as expected.
The question is how can I detect that the insertion has failed, to show a warning message with Toast.

Comment: I am struggling with a similar issue. Is there any chance you found an answer to your question by now?

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this problem. As a workaround, before inserting a new record, I check for duplicates with the following statement: `@Query( "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from Siniestros WHERE NSiniestro = :nSiniestro)")`     `fun existeSiniestro(nSiniestro: Long): Boolean`

Comment: Yeah that's an option. I figured out a way too. I am posting it. Maybe helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to debug my application. After a little bit of search I found a way to detect and handle result for insert operation which helped me quite a lot. It may help others too. Based on the provided code above:

***Dao:***

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun nuevo(siniestro: Siniestro): Long

@Transaction
suspend fun nuevoWithToast(siniestro: Siniestro) {
    val result = nuevo(siniestro)
    if (result == -1L) {
        //Use a Toast or Log to show failed operation
        //An update method can also be called depending on the strategy
    }
}
```

Key here is: a method with `@Insert` annotation can return a `Long` value. Finally call `nuevoWithToast` instead of `nuevo`

***Repository:***

```
suspend fun nuevo(siniestro: Siniestro){
   siniestroDao.nuevoWithToast(siniestro)
}
```